# Question about deduction in first order logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

My question is: Assume that $\Gamma\vdash\varphi$ and that $P$ is a predicate symbol which occurs *neither* in $\Gamma$ nor in $\varphi$.  Is there a deduction of $\varphi$ from $\Gamma$ in which $P$ doesn't occur?

My textbook suggests two possible approaches: one approach which makes use of two languages (one that contains $P$ and one that does not), and the other approach which considers the question whether $P$ can be systematically eliminated from a given deduction $\varphi$ from $\Gamma$.

I am really confused about where to start with this problem...how do I construct the two languages to use?

Answer (score 1):

Replace $P$ in every step of the proof with some other predicate variable $Q$ in the language (or even by a predicate constant like $\top$ or $\bot$), and the result will still be a valid proof which does not use $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever deductive system you are using, you have presumably proven Soundness and Completeness theorems for it. Then having a deduction in language $\mathcal{L}$ is equivalent to being logically entailed among $\mathcal{L}$-structures. What happens on the logical entailment side when you throw away the predicate symbol?

Comment: I see, if $P$ doesn't occur in $\Gamma$ or $\varphi$ and $\Gamma$ logically entails $\varphi$ in L, then $\Gamma$ logically entails $\varphi$ in L' where L' is L just without $P$.  Why is this the case?  Here I want to use the definition that $\Gamma$ logically entails $\varphi$ iff for every structure $U$ _for the language_ and every function $s: V \to |U|$ such that $U$ satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ with $s$, $U$ also satisfies $\varphi$ with $s$.

Comment: @cpumind - for every model $\mathcal M$ of the original language $\mathcal L$, you have to consider the $\mathcal L'$-reduct $\mathcal M'$ of $\mathcal M$ (see Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus & Jörg Flum & Wolfgang Thomas, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA38) (2nd ed 1994), page 38) where $\mathcal L'$ is the original language without the predicate symbol $P$. We have that for any $\varphi \in \mathcal L'$ : $\mathcal M \vDash \varphi$ **iff** $\mathcal M' \vDash \varphi$ and thus we conclude with $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ also for $\mathcal L'$.